# Android Map on V1 using the API Key Registered for Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I developed an application using Android Maps API v1 long back. Somehow debug.keystore got deleted and if I try to build the app again I am getting the below error.

Now, I can not get the api key for android google maps v1. My question is that can I get the new maps api key for android maps V2 and use it for the application which uses Maps api V1.

```
IOException processing: 26
    java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
        at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
        at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
        at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
        at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
        at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: you should Create a new API using Google Map V2..

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing and it was past the deadline to get a key for v1 and I didn't know, my solution was to just change the code to use v2 which wasn't hard at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Keys are not interchangeable. If you got not v1 key any more, then you are out of luck.

> Please let me know if any one of you know the solution to this problem

Use v2.

Answer (score 1):

Use map api v2, because map api v1 is deprecated now, you could not create new key using it. So better for you is use V2.